# How to show part of a map on a Live Tile in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, live-tile

I'm developing Windows Phone application using Bing maps, background tasks and live tiles. I'd like to show current neighborhood on a live tile (piece of a map). Is it somehow possible to show part of a map on a tile?

I guess instantiating Map object in background task and rendering part of the map as image won't fit into memory requirements.

Maybe there is a web service for returning map image for target coordinates, zoom and image size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a way to do this through the Virtual Earth service. You can read more about it [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/tip-day-windows-phone).

To summarize, you can get a square tile for a specific location just like this:

> http://tiles.virtualearth.net/api/GetMap.ashx?c=39.213413,-98.699930&w=800&h=800&b=r,stl.h,device.mobile,mkt.en-US&z=15&logo=no&da=n

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. I've found also this guide how to use tiles from Bing maps directly.

http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/bing-mapcontrol-offline-tiles-solution-wpdev-wp7dev/